# fwrite consuming all MemFree, fflush not working?

Tags: c, linux, file, disk

We have a data capture system that is connected to a very fast 10TB raid 0 jbod.

We receive 4 MiB data buffers at approximately 1.25 GB/s which are written to a sequential file which was opened with fopen, 10 GiB is fallocate'd, and written to with fwrite. every 10 GiB we fflush then fallocate gets another 10 GiB. Lastly it's closed after capture is complete with fclose.

The problem is that while the capture is underway, we can see /proc/meminfo MemFree drop, and Cached shoot up - i.e. the fflush seems to do nothing. This proceeds until we have about 200 MiB MemFree in the system, and now the data rate becomes extremely spikey, which causes our capture to fail.

We were hoping that the spikes would fall around the 10 GiB when we call fflush, but it just doesn't seem to do anything. The file isn't flushed until we call fclose.

Any reason for this behavior? using setvbuf(hFile, NULL, _IONBF, 0) doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Comment: I'm not sure what the specific problem is, but you might want to just use the lower level calls `open` and `write`. Is there some particular reason you need to use `fopen` and `fwrite`? Also, what benefit does `fallocate` provide? Space will be allocated when you write to the file.

Comment: AndySchweig The behavior also occurs using open/write/close. (I think the idea behind fallocate was to improve performance.)

Comment: Obvious question: Are you sure your disk array can write 1.25 GB/sec?

Comment: @duskwuff yes, 2x 1.25 GB/s have been used successfully under Windows.

Comment: since you are managing your own buffer, is it possible to write with O_DIRECT? That way your OS doesnt use its buffer cache to hold on to data in memory when writing? fwrite is buffering on its own too. There's probably some resource contention with all the buffers holding data. When you hit the upper limit of memory usage, you end up missing captures because your OS and/or stdio is busy managing the buffers.

Comment: The symptoms indicate less than optimal choices of [`/proc/sys/vm/dirty*`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt), or possibly bad choices or mount options for the filesystem used. I'd personally also use the low-level I/O interface (`<unistd.h>`, `<fcntl.h>`) instead of standard I/O (`<stdio.h>`), as stdio does all kinds of heuristics that may affect the operation; low-level I/O is simple, predictable, and robust, but needs a bit more thought to get right (wrt. short writes in particular) and efficient (write block sizes if O_DIRECT).

Comment: @FrancoSolleza O_DIRECT with the low-level functions did it! thanks! add a reply and i'll credit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see your free memory drop, that's your OS writing to its buffer cache (essentially, all available memory). In addition, stdio's `fwrite()` is buffering on its own. Because of this, there's some resource contention going on. When your OS hits the upper limits of available memory, this resource contention causes slower writes and high memory utilization. The bottleneck causes you to miss data captures.

Since you are managing your own buffer, it would be possible to use `write()` with `O_DIRECT` to avoid all this buffering.